# Converting NSData into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, xml, nsdictionary, nsdata

I get the data from an XML file and I am storing it in NSData object. I want to convert that NSData into an NSDictionary and store that data in a plist.

My code is as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fubar.com/sample.xml"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

To convert the data, I am using:

```
- (NSDictionary *)downloadPlist:(NSString *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10]; 
    NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];

    if (!err) {
        NSString *errorDescription = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        NSDictionary *samplePlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:responseData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&errorDescription];

        if (!errorDescription)
            return samplePlist;

        [errorDescription release];              
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Well, you need to read the XML file and extract the XML elements that belong in your dictionary.  How you do it depends on the structure of the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSString *newStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *newStr2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *newStr3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newStr1 , newStr2 , newStr3 , nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Login" ofType:@"plist"]; 
[dictionary writeToFile:path  atomically:YES];
//here Login is the plist name.
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 5):

or this:

```
NSString* dataStr  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
SBJSON *jsonParser = [SBJSON new];
NSDictionary* result = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:dataStr error:nil];
[jsonParser release];
[dataStr release];
```

Comment: This only works for JSON data, and the question is about XML data.